# What is the right way of building user favourites table (Performance)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I guess that title isn't very descriptive, so I will explain! I have table called users_favs where is stored all info about which posts user has liked, which post he has favourited and the same for comments. info there is stored as serealized array / or JSON who cares.

---

**Question:** What is better? Stay like this **or** to make 4 tables for each of the fields and store not in serealized version but like user_id => post_id???
What I think about second option is that after some time this field will be GIGANTIC. Also, I will need to make 4 queries (or with JOINS) to take all of the info from these tables.

[image]

Comment: Why the 's' at the end? Are you going to store multiple categories, posts, ... in 1 field? It would be better to make 1 record for each category, post, ... the user liked.

Comment: Yeah as I said now they are stored as serialized array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it in 1 table means that you'll only need 1 table access and 0 joins to get all the data. While storing it in 4 tables, you'll need at least 1 table access and n-1 joins, when you need n fields of information. Your result set at the end of the query will probably be the same, so the amount of data send over the network is independent of your table structure.

Comment: so what would you do?

Comment: I don't see any advantages in splitting it into 4 tables, so I would keep it in 1

Answer (score 0):

I presume a scenario when you will have data for fav_categories and other columns are null. Similarly for columns fav_posts, liked_posts, liked_comments. So there is a high probability  that in each row , only three columns will have data most of the time (id,user_id,any one of rest). If my assumptions are right and the use cases as well , then i would definitely go four four tables.

To add to above you can always choose from whether you want to make read-friendly or write-friendly.

Comment: Why would you assume that a user only will use 1 of the 4 columns? I would think that if he bothers to use a 'like' or 'favorite', he'll use the other functions as well.

Comment: Yes, but say the user has one fav_post, corresponding to that is it necessary to have liked_comments or liked_posts???

Comment: True, there are no guarantees. But if it's space you're worried about. Splitting it up into 4 tables requires for each table to store the id's per fav% or liked% item. So, when you store all 4 fields, you'll be using more space with 4 tables than with 1. It's a matter of choice. And since the title stated 'Performance' was preferable, diskspace (very cheap these days) is the thing to sacrifice.

Comment: Well said. But 'Performance' alone does not say what kind of performance. If you see, those four fields are not related (in case my view is correct). Else I totally agree with you in having one table. And as I already mentioned in the answer, it can be made either read friendly or write friendly.

Comment: They somewhat are related. They all are about the user's preferences.